# VB.Net Sorting on custom object

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I am new to VB.Net and I am using .Net Framework 2.0. I have a custom object in VB.Net with some complex hierarchy

Consider this is my object hierarchy

```
Person
  Addresses
     Address[1]
          S.No 1
          Street
          ....
     Address[2]
          S.No 2
          Street
          ....
     Address[3]
          **S.No 4**
          Street
          ....
     Address[4]
          **S.No 3**
          Street
          ....
```

Now I want to sort the Address object collection based on S.No. I am expecting the final output like the following:

```
Person
  Addresses
     Address[1]
          S.No 1
          Street
          ....
     Address[2]
          S.No 2
          Street
          ....
     Address[3]
          **S.No 3**
          Street
          ....
     Address[4]
          **S.No 4**
          Street
          ....
```

Comment: Please consider upgrading to at least 4.0, so much better framework.

Comment: Post the Class object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.Sort(T(), IComparer(Of T))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x(v=vs.80).aspx) to accomplish your task, if the "Addresses" is an array. If a list, you can use the [`list.Sort(IComparer(Of T))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/234b841s(v=vs.80).aspx) method.

Example code would be:

```
Class AddressComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Address)

    Public Function Compare(x As Address, y As Address) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Address).Compare
        ' Don't forget to handle "Nothing" values
        Return x.No.CompareTo(y.No)
    End Function
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim addressesArray() As Address = New Address(3) {}
    addressesArray(0) = New Address(1, "1")
    addressesArray(1) = New Address(2, "2")
    addressesArray(2) = New Address(4, "4")
    addressesArray(3) = New Address(3, "3")
    Array.Sort(addressesArray, New AddressComparer())

    Dim addressesList As New List(Of Address)()
    addressesList.Add(New Address(1, "1"))
    addressesList.Add(New Address(2, "2"))
    addressesList.Add(New Address(4, "4"))
    addressesList.Add(New Address(3, "3"))
    addressesList.Sort(New AddressComparer())
End Sub
```